# Indexing gzipped blobs in Azure Search

Tags: azure, gzip, azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to setup Azure Search over Azure Blob. The blobs are compressed using gzip.

When I try to index the blobs as-is, I get the exception :

"Error detecting index schema from data source: "Error processing blob https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/urlencodedname with content type ''. Status:UnsupportedMediaType, error:""

Is there a way to decompress (gunzip) before (or during) indexing within Azure Search ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Search blob indexer does support indexing ZIP archives (`application/zip` MIME type), but not gzip-compressed files. 
Please feel free to add a suggestion on [Azure Search UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search).

Comment: Done : https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/31432054-enabled-indexing-of-gzip-compressed-blobs